# What does the relation between mass and energy of a free particle mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, hamiltonian

What does the Hamiltonian for a free particle mean? Does it mean that the kinetic energy of the particle is in reverse relation with mass?
$H$ or $E=\hbar^{2}k^{2}/2m$.

Or better to ask: what's the relation between $k$ and $m$?

Comment: The Hamiltonian of a free particle is simply the Hamiltonian of a *non-interacting* particle, which would only then consist of a Kinetic energy term.

Comment: the question is about the relation between the mass and kinetic energy. (i should change the title)

Comment: The trivial rewriting $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ may help you resolve your confusions...

Comment: @Danu:  but $p$ is $h k$ here!

Comment: Exactly! So... what's your problem?

Comment: @Danu: now, what is $p$? is it $mv$ or $h k$

Comment: @P.A.M see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave

Comment: @glance: give me a abbreviation, i have read it before but can't get the above mentioned relation!!